# 3d stress contour

Tags: plotting

I have 4 matrix, each one is 9 by 36 by 60.

matrix 1 is the x coordinates
matrix 2 is the y coordinates
matrix 3 is the z coordinates

matrix 4 is the stress coordinates. I will not post the whole code as it will be too lengthy.

I am going to simplify here to just learn how to do it and learn the function. "ListContourPlot3D[{{x1,y1,z1,f1},{x2,y2,z2,f2},…}]

so the code below is a very simple version of the actual code.

```
ListContourPlot3D[{{1,1,1,1}, {1,1,2,2}, {1,2,2,1}, {2,2,2,2},
  {2, 1,2,1}, {2,2, 1,1}, {2, 1,1,1}}]
```

Comment: Post code, not pictures.

Comment: You need more data points.  `ListContourPlot3D` cannot make a contour with so few points.  Try `mydata = RandomReal[10, {50, 4}];
ListContourPlot3D[mydata]`  Also, eliminate `Contours->{1}` (Thanks anderstood)

Comment: Or, shorter, `mydata = RandomReal[10, {50, 4}]`.

Comment: if I understand the first part, you need something like `ListContourPlot[Transpose[Flatten/@{m1,m2,m3,m4}]]`